# telerik RadNotification show alert client side in update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I am trying to show alert message using RadNotification instead of regular web alert from javascript. Its not working for me not sure why. Any input is appreciated.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <telerik:RadNotification ID="RadNotificationAlert" runat="server" Position="TopCenter" Width="500"
        Height="125" OnCallbackUpdate="RadNotificationAlert_CallbackUpdate" OnClientShowing="OnClientShowing"
        LoadContentOn="EveryShow" AutoCloseDelay="120000" RenderMode="Lightweight" Title="Error" 
        Skin="MetroTouch" EnableRoundedCorners="true" VisibleOnPageLoad="false"  
        ShowCloseButton="false" KeepOnMouseOver="false" CssClass="timeoutNotification" ShowSound="info"  Style="z-index: 300000">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="notificationContent">
                <asp:Literal ID="lblRadNotificationAlert" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <telerik:RadButton Skin="MetroTouch" ID="continueSession" runat="server" Text="Continue Your Session"
                    Style="margin-top: 10px;" AutoPostBack="false" OnClientClicked="RadNotificationAlertClientClose" Width="190px">
                </telerik:RadButton>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </telerik:RadNotification>
    < More code here >   
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In area here I have written Mode code here..one of which is a submit button.
on submit I do validation and if anything missing then show alert...that method I can see is getting called . Below is the javascript code:

```js
var radAlert = $('#<%=RadNotificationAlert.ClientID %>');
$('#lblRadNotificationAlert').text('select default template');
radAlert.show();
// alert('select default template');
return false;
```

In the commented code, I can see that alert.
When I put break point, I can see my code step through each line above.
Why is the radAlert not showing then?

```
.notificationContent {
  width: 160px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center
}
```

Comment: "_`</asp:UpdatePanel></ContentTemplate>`_" Why is this out of order? Shouldn't it be `</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>`?

Comment: will fix that. I just copy pasted the tags to give an idea there is more code below and then it finishes

Comment: you copy and pasted... so it was wrong in the source code too?

Comment: Ignore...found my issue. I should be using RadWindowManager. I got it working using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

RadWindowManager should be used if you want an "alert". I was using the incorrect control!